# How can I speed up my Java game's FPS?

Tags: java, optimization, frame-rate

I am making a Java game, and the game lags a lot when I paint out the graphics.
The way I am currently painting out the graphics is to make a `BufferedImage`, get the `Graphics2D` from it, then do a whole bunch of:

```
g2d.drawImage(loadedImages.getImage(),x,y,null);
```

After I print all of the images to the `BufferedImage`, I paint the `BufferedImage` to the screen.

There are a lot of images I paint to the `BufferedImage`. Is there a better way to do this that would speed up the painting time?
I do not know much about graphics and graphic cards. Should I use a graphics card? Should I paint directly to the screen? Should I use something entirely different than `drawImage()`?

Comment: Perhaps it's a good idea to look into OpenGL. You can use it for the same purposes (perhaps with a bit more effort), but it can be accelerated much better than `Graphics2D`.

Comment: I enjoyed using LWJGL (Light Weight Java Game Library, an OpenGL wrapper) directly -- have to write a thin wrapper, but then it's great for 2D ;-) There are other existing game libraries including Slick2D. Java does support *some* 2D acceleration, but I always felt it hit or miss.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Generate the 'lot of images' in the code.

Comment: The only real advantage of using a 'background' image in a double buffered component is if there is a complex scene in it which either does not change, or changes only rarely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance should be good if you're drawing a reasonable amount of images.

Make sure you're not creating new `BufferedImage`s every time you draw to the screen. For example, you might have a `Resources` [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) in which you manage all of your images so that you only load and unload each image once.

---

If you really want more performance, you'll want to use OpenGL. See [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/), [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/), or [JOGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL). You may also want to consider 2D graphics libraries like [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/).

Comment: What is the difference between LWJGL and LibGDX?

Comment: LWJGL is better for desktop development, while libgdx can work on both Android and desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it useful to extend [java.awt.Canvas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) and use

```
BufferStrategy bs;
void init() {
    createBufferStrategy(2);// or 3 for triple-buffering
    bs = getBufferStrategy();
}
```

and then the actual `draw()` method looks like

```
void draw() {
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, w, h, null);
    // Draw more things here...
    // You can also make calls like `myObject.draw(g)` and whatever
    //    you draw onto `g` within those calls will show up.
    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}
```

This is what I use for drawing a lot of things. And then within each `myObject.draw(g)` call, there are sometimes multiple other similar calls all chained up. Most often my main `draw()` method has one or two `for` loops in it that just say `for(Entity e: entities) e.draw(g);` or something similar. Then the whole drawing chain is kicked off from there.